# Secure REST APIs with keycloak token in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, keycloak

When users hit any API end point from my project it should verify access token.

If the user is sending it into header and if header is not there than it should say unauthorized. and if user's request has credentials like email and password than application should generate access token using keycloak credentials type.

I tried the same but it throwing an exception like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.lookupCachedKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:85)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:69)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:44)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:55)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:37)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:87)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.AbstractUndertowKeycloakAuthMech.keycloakAuthenticate(AbstractUndertowKeycloakAuthMech.java:110)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletKeycloakAuthMech.authenticate(ServletKeycloakAuthMech.java:92)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:244)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:230)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:124)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:92)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

code I am using is shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
      private DataSource dataSource;

     @Autowired
       public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
          keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
          auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
       }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .addFilterAfter(new SecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)).
        and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/api/user/signout")
          .permitAll()
          .and().httpBasic().disable();
      }
      @Override
      public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
      }

      @Bean
        @Override
        protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
            return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
              new SessionRegistryImpl());
        }

      @Bean
       public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
          return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
       }
}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
         resources.resourceId("test");
            RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
                "serverurl");
            tokenServices.setClientId("test");
            tokenServices.setClientSecret("secret");
            tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(new KeycloakAccessTokenConverter());
            resources.tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    private class KeycloakAccessTokenConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter {

        @Override
        public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
            OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = super.extractAuthentication(map);
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getAuthorities();
            if (map.containsKey("realm_access")) {
                Map<String, Object> realm_access = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("realm_access");
                if(realm_access.containsKey("roles")) {
                    ((Collection<String>) realm_access.get("roles")).forEach(r -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)));
                }
            }
            return new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request(),oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The application (Resource Owner) shouldn't generate/modify access tokens. It's KC (Authorization server) the one who builds and signs them. Applications only exchange/parse the access tokens: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-43

Comment: But in my case application who will be accessing the web services is also belong to us and authorization server is also ours and resource server is also belong to us. But we want to secure all our REST apis because later on all apis will be exposed and will be accessible by third party applications(angular application or might be any)

Comment: It shouldn't matter which service belong to who. The responsible for assigning access tokens is the Authorization Server and not the Resource Owner.

Comment: Than what should I change in my code and where? Can you please guide me as I'm new to this concept and oAuth framework